# php settings does not work at all

Tags: php, apache

I have a Linux apache2 webserver with php version 7.0.22. It looks like the settings does not work at all :(

The .ini file is on the location: `/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini` according to `phpinfo()`. When I look into the `/etc/php/7.0/apache2` folder I see three files `php.ini` (the file that the settings are telling me that is in use),`php.ini.save` and `php.ini.ucf-dist`.

So I looked for `allow_url_include` and it was `off`, I change it to `On` and then `allow_url_fopen = On`. I did this to all of the .ini files saved them restarted apache2 and refreshed the phpinfo() page and nothing happened. 
I tried to change another settings in all of the .ini files and did the same thing and nothing happened. I have permission 777 on all of the .ini files (not smart, but I'am just trying to get this thing working).
So is there maybe some other settings that I need to change so I can update the settings for real? Any idea?

**UPDATE:**

And this is in the Additional .ini files parsed field:

/etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/15-xml.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-dom.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-exif.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-gd.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-iconv.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-json.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-phar.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-posix.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-readline.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-wddx.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-xsl.ini, /etc/php/7.0/apache2/conf.d/20-zip.ini

Comment: is there any other file listed inside phpinfo _Additional .ini files parsed_ section?

Comment: Look at my update :)

Comment: Could you format your text and make it readable?

Answer (score 0):

They might have been overrewritten by .htaccess http://docs.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php#configuration.changes.apache

or even in the php code http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Comment: `allow_url_*` are changeable in `PHP_INI_SYSTEM` and editing value inside htaccess will not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `grep -r allow_url_include /etc/php/7.0` and see if that directive is defined anywhere else in your configuration path.

Also, make sure the setting in your ini file is not preceded by a semi-colon which is a comment.  Depending on your distribution, this can be the case with defaults and it might read like this:

```lsp
; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-include
; allow_url_include = Off
```

So in addition to changing the setting to `On`, you'd need to remove the `;`

```lsp
; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include = On
```

Comment: Looks like allow_url_include and allow_url_open are On everywhere and not commented out in any of these files